# _ah_SESSION does not show up even with proper configuration

Tags: google-app-engine

I did enable sessions in the appengine-web.xml file. My application loads properly in GAE. However, no entity named '_ah_SESSION' shows up under 'datastore viewer'. Any idea what is going on? Anything undocumented going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your tests you delete _ah_SESSION from the datastore it might still exist in memcache.

Two ways to make _ah_SESSION reappear:

1) Delete the JSESSIONID cookie and reload your page. This will create a new _ah_SESSION entry immediately albeit for a new session.

2) Clear memcache (this addresses the issue more directly):

You can flush the memcache from the old appengine console at https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer ...then reload the page and again _ah_SESSION will appear immediately. I could not find this option in the new console.